# Exportar fecha a excel vba desde una pagina web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, excel, vba

Estoy intentando exportar desde una página web (https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=COP&amount=1) los datos de la tabla **1 Colombian Peso Rates table**. El problema es que no me exporta la fecha. Alguien me puede colaborar con eso.Anexo imagen de la tabla para exportar tabla e imagen después de exportar la tabla a excel.

Gracias.

[image: Imagen de la tabla que quiero exportar]

[image: Imagen después de exportar tabla a excel.]

### El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
Sub Actualizar_datos()
'Ejecutamos a la macro Elimina_Datos para eliminar la conexión, la querytable y los datos
Call Elimina_Datos
'Creamos nueva conexión con la web que contiene la tabla o datos que necesitamos
  
 With Sheets("CONVERSION").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=
"URL;https://xe.com/currencytables/?from=COP&date=2018-05-09", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
'indicamos el nombre de la querytable, debemos acabarla con _1 de lo contrario, el sistema otorgará un valor numérico
    .Name = "Colombian Peso Rates table"
    'ajustamos las columnas
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    'actualizamos los datos cada minuto
    .RefreshPeriod = 60
    'descargamos los datos de la tabla 1
    .WebTable = "1"
    'actualizamos datos en segundo plano
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
 End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Elimina_Datos()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cnn As Object
'eliminamos la conexión que hemos creado
For Each cnn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
If ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0 Then cnn.Delete
Next cnn
With Sheets("CONVERSION")
filas = Application.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
columnas = Application.CountA(.Range("1:1"))
'eliminamos todos los contenidos de la tabla
'Eliminamos la tabla
If filas And columnas > 0 Then
.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(filas, columnas)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
.Range("A1").Select
End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Tu macro, cuando creas la conexión, usas `"URL;https://xe.com/currencytables/?from=COP&date=2018-05-09"`. Al final de este string tienes la fecha 2018-05-09. ¿No puedes extraerla de ahí?

Comment: Con ese link no podía ya que la fecha estaba fija , entonces no se iba a actualizar la fecha. Este link si permite la actualización de las fechas. https://xe.com/currencytables/?from=COP& . Pero no me exporta la fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Logré exportar la fecha. 
Este es el código.

```
 Sub WebDataImport()
 On Error GoTo ControlErr

Dim strURL As String
Dim strDestino As String, strReportName As String
Dim numConnections As Integer, i As Integer

'vars
numConnections = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
strDestino = "A1"
strReportName = "Reporte Mensual"
'strURL = InputBox("Indique URL origen", "Mensaje")

'check url data
If strURL <> Empty Then

'custom url address
strURL = "URL;https://xe.com/currencytables/?from=COP&" & strURL

'clean previous connections
If numConnections > 0 Then
For i = 1 To numConnections
ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).Delete
Next i
End If

'clean datasheet
Sheets(7).Select
Sheets(7).Cells.Clear

'control excel app
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'get web query
With Sheets(7).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strURL _
, Destination:=Range(strDestino))
.Name = strReportName
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

'control excel app
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'final message
MsgBox "La importación ha finalizado", vbInformation, "Mensaje"

End If

Exit Sub

ControlErr:

MsgBox "Error: " & ERR.Description, vbCritical, "Mensaje"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ya es decisión si prefieren que solicite agregar la url en el formulario que aparece o no, des habilitando el comando. Por otra  parte tengo que modificar la macro para que solo me exporte la tabla y no la información que esta antes de ella. Si alguien me colabora con esa inquietud le agradezco. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hacer solicitud xhr. No se necesita un navegador web

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, hTable As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=COP&amount=1", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With CreateObject("htmlFile")
        .Write sResponse
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    End With

    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "x-rates"
    WriteTable hTable

End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As Object, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, R As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    R = startRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                R = R + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Excel:**

[image: Excel]

---

**Pagina web:**

[image: Web]